# Use array.join() to implode classname array javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I have some html tags and I am trying to join them using javascript array.

I have tried printing out the array to see what it looks like. If it try printing out one array item, it works but the whole array doesn't show

```html
<p>Click the button to join the array elements into a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p class="demo">Banana</p>
<p class="demo">Orange</p>
<p class="demo">Appl</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = document.querySelectorAll(".demo")[];
  var y = document.getElementById("demo");
  y.innerHTML = fruits.join(',');
}
</script>
```

I expect it to join the classname array together and print out a result but it shows nothing. I am not so good at javascript and would appreciate the help.

Comment: `var fruits = document.querySelectorAll(".demo")[];` - what do you expect this to do? I don't recognise the syntax, and it seems to give me a syntax error when I try a similar construct in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.querySelectorAll returns a collection and not an array. You need to use Array.from() to convert into an array

```js
function myFunction() {
var fruits = document.querySelectorAll(".demo");//Outputs a collection
//Change to array
  var fruitArray = Array.from(fruits).map(el => el.textContent);
  var y = document.getElementById("demo");
  y.innerHTML += fruitArray.join(',');
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to join the array elements into a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p class="demo">Banana</p>
<p class="demo">Orange</p>
<p class="demo">Appl</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do by adding `[]` to the end of your query selector code; that doesn't turn it into an array, if that's what you thought. `document.querySelectorAll` returns a collection of HTML elements, but not an actual array. To convert it, you have some options. You can do this:

`var fruits = [...document.querySelectorAll(".demo")];`

`...` is the spread operator, and it will spread out the resulting collection into the new array. Or you can do this:

`var fruits = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".demo"));`

Or you can, of course, manually loop over the collection and push to an array, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Also, as the spread operator and `Array.from` method are both from ES6, I'd suggest switching over to using `let` or `const` instead of `var`, as those have block scope (and, in the case of const, constant-value enforcement) that are much more useful than the function scope of the older `var`.

Comment: It may also be useful to note that, although `Array.from` and spread syntax make it easier, you don't need ES6 syntax to get a true array from an "array-like" object. You can also do `var fruits = Array.prototype.slice.apply(null, document.querySelectorAll(".demo"));` which works fine in ES5.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fruits = document.querySelectorAll(".demo")
```

This will contain all elements

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```js
function myFunction() {

  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var fruits = Object.keys(el).
              filter(function(v){
                return el[v].innerText !== undefined;
              })
              .map(function(v, i, o) {
                return el[v].innerText
              })
              .join(" ");
  
  console.log(fruits);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to join the array elements into a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p class="demo">Banana</p>
<p class="demo">Orange</p>
<p class="demo">Appl</p>

<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's helpful to provide an explanation along with the working solution so that the OP  and other future readers understand the reasons for your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = [];
  document.querySelectorAll(".demo").forEach(x=>fruits.push(x.innerText));  
  demo.innerHTML = fruits.join`,`;
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = [];
  document.querySelectorAll(".demo").forEach(x=>fruits.push(x.innerText));  
  demo.innerHTML = fruits.join`,`;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to join the array elements into a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p class="demo">Banana</p>
<p class="demo">Orange</p>
<p class="demo">Appl</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

querySelectorAll returns a NodeList. You need to convert it to an Array before using join.